# Prove whether the following transformation is linear or not.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I'm not sure if I'm going wrong with the proof, but I'm getting my answer as, the transformation is linear, whereas according to our teacher, it is not supposed to be linear.

Q. $T(v_1, v_2) = (v_1, v_1)$ is not a linear transformation. Prove it.

My Working:
So, since this is in two dimensional space, as the input and output are 2D coordinates, or matrices, the same two rules for linear transforms apply, except the inputs are matrices
$$T(a_1+ a_2)= T(a_1)+ T(a_2)$$
$$T(c*a_1) = c*T(a_1)$$
where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are $2\times 1$ matrices.

Now, let $a_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
let $a_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$$T(a_1+ a_2)= T(a_1)+ T(a_2)$$
$$T(a_1+ a_2)= T\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}+  T\begin{bmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}+  \begin{bmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
v_1+w_1 \\
v_1 +w_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is true.

The same obviously holds true for the second statement as well.

Thus, I am able to prove that since the linear transformation satisfies the two equations, the transformation is linear. I'm not sure if I've gone wrong somewhere, in which case I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: The transformation $T$ received *two* inputs, then your approach is not correct.

Comment: Read this a few times:  "Prove whether the following linear transformation is linear or not"

Comment: @user1027216 wait i dont understand, then how do you prove if a transformation in 2D is linear or not? because i looked it up and tried to follow what is mentioned [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/linear-transformations/a/visualizing-linear-transformations/)

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar Before I continue, which is in fact the question I should have asked myself. What does $(v_1,v_2)$ mean to you?

Comment: @user1027216 they are coordinates of a vector in 2D

Comment: @user1027216 my bad, i shouldve mentioned it in the question! sorry!

Comment: Well, so I deleted my post.  Please clarify the notation.

Comment: You did not give a description of what kind of things $v_1,v_2$ are in the "Q" statement of the problem, but you included in "My Working" that these are "in two dimensional space, as the input and output are 2D coordinates."  It is hard to tell if you are correct in drawing that conclusion.  If $v_1,v_2$ are real numbers, then it would be clearer to describe them as such in formulating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. You can remind your teacher that every matrix generates some linear transformation. In our case it is
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\
1 &0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Certainly
$$
A\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I am assuming that $(v_1,v_2)$ are the coordinates of a vector in two-dimensional space.

Comment: Well, that's a real problem given by the OP. If that is the interpretation, then you are correct. If they are vectors then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar You are welcome. But please double check if the formulation was exactly the same as it is here.